# Slideshow with multiple animation and Viewpager images

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slideshow

I have `listactivity` app forming many rows , one row is images Slideshow , when you click
the row open activity showing `ImageView` , also there is optionmenu of one item which is( slideshow animation setting  ), when you click it , it open checkbox preference 
animations screen with multiple checkboxes each one apply different animation to images
slideshow ,where user determine either to slide images with many animations available by 
check its checkbox animation name or when uncheck all the checkboxs so the slideshow activity
must show images in viewpager pattern .

`android:defaultValue="true"` for first animation which is fade_in animation.
BUT: when you open slideshow activity its open the images in imagepager pattern ,and **ignoring** `android:defaultValue="true"` for fade_in checkbox,

then after go to preference screen to choose another animation then back to slideshow
activity , it doesn't apply the new animation , i have to press back button many times
till finish all images scrolled in pager then it apply the next animation ,
and sometimes it stuck on image pager and freeze's ,the normal behavior is applying 
the next animation once press back button which return to slideshow .

another thing when i was in image `viewpager` pattern and scroll it , 
it scroll a few number of images then back to first image then i scroll images again 
and suddenly it back to first image one and so on .

**whole project can be downloaded from**  [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/bcp58397lmub376/Slideshow.rar)

any help will be appreciated.

**SlideShow.java**

```
public class SlideShow extends Activity {

public int currentimageindex=0;
Timer timer;
TimerTask task;
ImageView slidingimage;

  private int[] IMAGE_IDS = {
        R.drawable.day_one_1, R.drawable.day_one_2, R.drawable.day_one_3,
        R.drawable.day_one_4, R.drawable.day_one_5, R.drawable.day_one_6,
        R.drawable.day_one_7, R.drawable.day_one_8, R.drawable.day_one_9,
        R.drawable.day_one_10, R.drawable.day_one_11, R.drawable.day_one_12,
        R.drawable.day_one_13, R.drawable.day_one_14, R.drawable.day_one_15,
        R.drawable.day_one_16,R.drawable.day_one_17,R.drawable.day_one_18, 
        R.drawable.day_one_19,R.drawable.day_one_20  
        };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.slide);
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
 // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            AnimateandSlideShow();              
        }
    };

    int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

    int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {

         mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
    }

    }, delay, period);             

}      

private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    boolean animation = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation", true);             
    boolean animation_one = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_one", false);
    boolean animation_two = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_two", false);    
    boolean animation_three = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_three", false);
    boolean animation_four = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_four", false);
    boolean animation_five = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_five", false);              

 if (animation == true) {   
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);               
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);   

}else if(animation_one == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;        
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);        
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);   

}else if (animation_two == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);       
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  

}else if (animation_three == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);       
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  

}else if(animation_four == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;        
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in_2);        
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);   

}else if (animation_five == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flip);       
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  


}else if(animation == false && animation_one == false && animation_two == false){
    Intent intent = new Intent(SlideShow.this, ImagePager.class);                                     
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

   @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent p = new Intent("com.test.test.SETTING");
        startActivity(p);
    break;
    }

return false; 
}
   }
```

**ImagePager.java**

```
  public class ImagePager extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pager);

    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myimagepager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}

     private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.day_one_1, R.drawable.day_one_2, R.drawable.day_one_3,
        R.drawable.day_one_4, R.drawable.day_one_5, R.drawable.day_one_6,
        R.drawable.day_one_7, R.drawable.day_one_8, R.drawable.day_one_9,
        R.drawable.day_one_10, R.drawable.day_one_11, R.drawable.day_one_12,
        R.drawable.day_one_13, R.drawable.day_one_14, R.drawable.day_one_15,
        R.drawable.day_one_16,R.drawable.day_one_17,R.drawable.day_one_18, 
        R.drawable.day_one_19,R.drawable.day_one_20  

    };

public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {   
    Activity activity;
    int[] imageArray;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArra) {
        imageArray = imgArra;
        activity = act;   
        }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageArray.length;   
        }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pager, null);   

        ImageView im=(ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.pager_imageView);

        im.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout, 0);
           return layout;   
           }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);   
        }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);   
        }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null; 
        }
    } 
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

   @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent p = new Intent("com.test.test.SETTING");
        startActivity(p);
    break;
    }

return false;
}
   }
```

Comment: Please tell me if I understood correctly, your app starts with `ImagePager`, then the user hits the settings and changes animation setting to `true`, and you want the animations start to play when they press back button in settings activity (returning to `ImagePager`)?

Answer (score 0):

Please post the project to be work out a proper solution mean while try using this

First of all as you have declared the `ImageView slidingimage;` as an instance variable, declare the  `Animation rotateimage` as an instance variables and use it as

```
 rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);
```

Now once you add the animation to imageview call the `invalidate()` method inside the if loops

```
slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage)
slidingimage.invalidate();
```

And in your imagePager class make `ViewPager myPager` as static instance variable `private static ViewPager myPager` and add this code to the class

```
public static void refreshPager(){
    if(myPager != null)
        myPager.invalidate();
}
```

And in your `settings` class call this method on the `onBackPressed()` event

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ImagePager.refreshPager();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

***EDIT***

All you just need to do is this, add this code in your `Slide.java` file after the `setContentView(R.layout.main);` and before `final Handler mHandler = new Handler();`

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    if(getPrefs.getBoolean("Initialization", false) == false){
         SharedPreferences.Editor edit = getPrefs.edit();
         edit.putBoolean("animation_one", true);
         edit.putBoolean("Initialization", true);
         edit.commit();
    }
```

Like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    if(getPrefs.getBoolean("Initialization", false) == false){
         SharedPreferences.Editor edit = getPrefs.edit();
         edit.putBoolean("animation_one", true);
         edit.putBoolean("Initialization", true);
         edit.commit();
    }
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
 // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            AnimateandSlideShow();              
        }
    };

    int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

    int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

    Timer timer = new Timer

    // Some more code............
```

The preference file was not created only ;)

***EDIT 2***
In you `Slide.java` file declare a boolean like this

```
public boolean loaded ;
```

and code your else if like this

```
else if(animation_one == false && animation_two == false && animation_three == false 
        && animation_four == false && animation_five == false){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Slide.this, ImagePager.class);  
    if(loaded)
    startActivity(intent);
    loaded = true;
}
```

Create a static variable in `Slide.java` public static TimerTask task; and in your `ImagePager.java` add this code `if(imageArra.length-1 == position)Slide.task.cancel();` in `instantiateItem()` method like this

```
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pager, null);   

    ImageView im=(ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.myimage);             
    im.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout, 0);
    if(imageArra.length-1 == position)
        Slide.task.cancel();
       return layout;   
       }
```

Hope this works

Comment: my dear i add your piece of code but still the problems also it rise varification dialoge 
when click on setting menu to change animation , i post link to whole project , 
you can download it if you want and check it .
problems:1-app must start with fade_in animation coz it set android:defaultValue="true" 
but the app ignore it and start with viewpager.

Comment: 2- sliding images in pager pattern restart after few images to begain from first image .
3-after go to preference screen to choose another animation then back to slideshow 
activity , it doesn't apply the new animation ,
i have to press back button many times till finish all images scrolled in pager then
it apply the next animation ,thanks a lot.

Comment: @androidqq6 : Ok let me check the project & in view pager the next page is inflated and destroyed after only a certain number of swipes

Comment: and what about the other 2 problems any advice my dear , thanks

Comment: 1st and 3rd are solved right ?, and in 2nd you need stop the endless loop or what ?Can you explain a bit

Comment: @androidqq6 : Please check the edit i have modified the code a bit

Comment: my dear the edit code just solve the preference which start correctly with animation i predetermined in code by android:defaultValue="true", but still pager after few images scrolling it start from first image again and second if you uncheck all checkboxs and start pager pattern and scroll images in pager then chose another animation and back to slide screen you have to click back button till the new animation start, thanks

Comment: unfourtinatlly nothing change ,still pager after few images scrolling it start from first image again and second if you uncheck all checkboxs and start pager pattern and scroll images in pager then chose another animation and back to slide screen you have to click back button till the new animation start, thanks